# FOSRestBundle Catching All Routes

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to integrate FOSRestBundle into my application.

I want to use it only when a route matches like `^/api`.

I really don't know how to use this bundle, and i think the documentation is pretty bad. (No offense).

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json', 'xml'], fallback_format: 'html' }
```

When i request any route from my browser, i get this error:

> No matching accepted Response format could be determined

I just want to match the routes starting with ^/api.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `zones` feature:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    zone:
        - { path: ^/api/* }
```

read more about it in official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html#zone-listener

Comment: I don't know but maybe just maybe that feature is deprecated because i'm getting an error like "that option is unrecognized".

Comment: You need to use version 2.0 (latest master or 2.0.0-BETA2) - https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle

Comment: I'v updated to latest version (dev-master). There is no error but still not working as rest client :/ :(

Comment: What do You mean with "still not working as rest client"?

Comment: I'v updated my routes, now i'm not getting that strange error above but now all api routes neither found nor working..

Comment: With `zone` feature you `format_listener` shouldn't process response on any other url than the one covered by zone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106036/discussion-between-pawel-mikolajczuk-and-r-canser-yanbakan).